# Python input not being correctly evaluated

Tags: python, input

I have the following list of tuples:

```
possible_moves(Board,'White') = 
[('60', '50'),
 ('60', '40'),
 ('61', '51'),
 ('61', '41'),
 ('62', '52'),
 ('62', '42'),
 ('63', '53'),
 ('63', '43'),
 ('64', '54'),
 ('64', '44'),
 ('65', '55'),
 ('65', '45'),
 ('66', '56'),
 ('66', '46'),
 ('67', '57'),
 ('67', '47'),
 ('71', '52'),
 ('71', '50'),
 ('76', '57'),
 ('76', '55')]
```

If I run the following code it prints True as expected

```
if ('64','44') in possible_moves(Board,'White'):
    print(True)
```

However when i get a user to enter the same input, it prints False.

```
move = input("Enter Move as a tuple of strings:")
if move in possible_moves(Board,'White'):
    print(True)
elif move not in possible_moves(Board,'White'):
    print(False)
```

The out put reads

```
Enter Move as a tuple of strings:('64','44') 
False
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: It's because `input()` returns a string, _not_ the tuple you want. `('64','44')` and `"('64','44')"` are different.

Comment: `input()` returns a string, even if the user typed something that _looks_ like a tuple.

Comment: I believe the `python 2` `input` function used to evaluate the input.   They included a `raw-input` function which didn't evaluate the input string.  Don't use Python 2.x any more, it's no longer supported.  There are safe eval functions if you want to simulate the behavior, but you have to look that up yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This is the same difference as in 42 and "42". Both look the same, but they are completely different: one is an *integer* number, while the latter is a *string*.

So, you needed to build the tuple you are looking for:

```
row = input("Enter a row: ")
col = input("Enter a column: ")
move = (row, col)
```

EDIT: It seems that your collection of moves is of strings instead of integers. I did not realize, probably because it is not intuitive that way. I thus removed the call to `int()` (which converts a string into a number). The original code was:

```
row = int(input("Enter a row: "))
col = int(input("Enter a column: "))
move = (row, col)
```

And now it is really possible to check whether *move* is inside the possible moves.

Comment: The moves are tuples of strings, so you shouldn't call `int()` on the input.

Comment: Thanks, @John Gordon, did not realized about that. Solved now.